# Convert a path to querystring using iis rewriter

Tags: iis, web-config

Using IIS rewriter for IIS 7.5 I would like to have the following URL:
http://www.contoso.com/FOLDER1/FOLDERX/PLACE2/SomeImportantText/1bab8a84-8d06-478f-badd-6af4248661a7/MoreImportantText
convert to:
http://www.contoso.com/something.aspx?X=SomeImportantText&Y=1bab8a84-8d06-478f-badd-6af4248661a7&Z=MoreImportantText
the domain should be excluded so that this is a relative url.
How do I do this in the web.config file

I am currently trying:

```
    <rules>
         <rule name="Rewrite Language">
                <match url="^/FOLDER1/FOLDERX/PLACE2/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/something.aspx?X={R:1}&amp;Y={R:2}&amp;Z={R:3}" /> 
         </rule>
    </rules>
```

Comment: <rules>
  <rule name="Rewrite Language">
  <match url="[/FOLDER1/FOLDERX/PLACE2/]{1}[/]{2}[/]{3}" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/something.aspx?X={R:1}&Y={R:2}&Z={R:3}" />
  </rule>
            </rules>

Comment: You should edit your question to include this.

Comment: I have tried both of these and they are not working:
    
    <rule name="Rewrite Language1">
       <match url="^http://([^/]*)/FOLDER1/FOLDERX/PLACE2/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{R:1}/something.aspx?X={R:2}&amp;Y={R:3}&amp;Z={R:4}" /> 
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite Language2">
       <match url="^/FOLDER1/FOLDERX/PLACE2/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url="/something.aspx?X={R:1}&amp;Y={R:2}&amp;Z={R:3}" /> 
    </rule>

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
         <rule name="Working Rewrite Language">
            <match url="^FOLDER1/FOLDERX/PLACE2/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="something.aspx?X={R:1}&amp;Y={R:2}&amp;Z={R:3}" /> 
         </rule>
```